# Permission issue with Podman

Tags: containers, buildah

I have installed Podman on Ubuntu 18.04 and it seemed to install without issue but...

When I type `podman--version` I get:

> podman version 1.3.0-dev

But if I then type `podman ps` I get:

> Error: could not get runtime: cannot make directory /home/redacted/.config/containers: mkdir /home/redacted/.config/containers: permission denied

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podman when running rootless attempts to create content in the home directory.  In this case it looks like the homedir is /home/redacted.

The user running podman is not allowed to write to the homedir /home/redacted.

Comment: The user redacted is running podman and has access to write to its own homedir. Is there any other reason this could be happening?

Comment: Turns out that for some reason root was the owner of the .config folder. I changed the owner to redacted and everything is working now.

Comment: @Clownfused, how did you the owner change? I do not understand system handling.